# Run FB.logout() when page opens

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is there a way to run FB.logout() when the page first loads? Or is it only possible when the user clicks it and triggers it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need jQuery, simply add the call to FB.logout in your window.fbAsyncInit function:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'appid',
    channelURL : '//site/channel.html'
    status     : true, 
    cookie     : true, 
    oauth      : true,
    xfbml      : true
  });

  FB.logout();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using JQuery just fire the FB.logout() call once the page is in a 'ready' state. Docs can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). You could also just use the built in javascript method `window.onload`.